# How to Sort an array of dictionary arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I get `categories` from my database with this code:

```
db.collection(DatabaseRef.categories).document(DatabaseRef.categoriesDoc).getDocument { snap, error in

            guard error == nil, let snap = snap else {
                return
            }

            let data = snap.data()!

            for (k,v) in data {
                self.categories.append([Int(k) ?? 0 : v])
            }

            self.categoryCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
```

Here is my categories variable:

```
var categories: [[Int: Any]] = []
// categories = [[1: "category1"], [3: "category3"], [2: "category2"]]
```

I would like to sort `categories` before I reload my collectionview. So the categories should look like the following instead:

`// categories = [[1: "category1"], [2: "category2"], [3: "category3"]`]

I tried the following:

```
let sortedCategories = categories.sorted{ $0.key > $1.key}
```

But I am getting this error: `Unable to infer closure type in the current context`

Comment: Each dictionary has more than one key, `$0.key` is totally invalid. Why do you have a bunch of dictionaries with only a single key value pair, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `categories` is a an array of dictionaries, `$0` and `$1` are *dictionaries* `[Int: Any]`, not key value pairs `(key: Int, value: Any)`, although they each contain exactly one key value pair.

Therefore, one way to access the one and only key value pair in each dictionary is `.keys.first!`.

```
categories.sorted(by: { $0.keys.first! < $1.keys.first! })
```

Frankly, I don't think `[[Int: Any]]` is a suitable data structure for `categories`. If there are no duplicate `k`s, you should just use a `[Int: Any]`. And you would insert the data this way:

```
for (k,v) in data {
    self.categories[[Int(k) ?? 0] = v
}
```

You can use the original code you used for sorting:

```
categories.sorted{ $0.key > $1.key }
```

And after sorting, you will get a `[(key: Int, value: Any)]`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. reason I am using this `[[Int: Any]]` is because I was told collectionView works best with arrays; e.g. for number of rows in collection return `categories.count`... With that I keep them in an array so its easier to deal with in the collectionView; maybe I was told incorrectly?

Comment: Because dictionaries don't have a defined ordering, they don't have a defined `first` key, so I would caution against using this. The whole premise doesn't really much make sense, anyway

Comment: makes sense; thats why for the `Int` in the dictionary I only have one key for each so the `first` will always be that key. I am using numbers so with your sorting solution I can sort the `categories` by numbers.

Comment: @user12669401 "works best" is rather vague... in what way? But anyway, I still recommend you to use a `[Int: Any]`, and not the weird `[[Int: Any]]`. After sorting, you get an array in both cases.

Comment: Got ya! Trying that now

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yeah, OP _might_ have a bigger problem here, but `first` is fine _in this specific case_, no? According to how OP has initialised it, each dictionary only has one entry, so `first` is defined, right?

Comment: @user12669401 The whole point of a dictionary is to be able to look up values quickly by a key. If you have only one key/value pair in the dictionary, then wht's the point of using a dictionary? What are you trying to achieve by having those dicts?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, it's "fine", it just doesn't make any sense in the broader context

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I want to be able to show the categories in my collectionView sorted by their `key`. I was told this would work best if they are arrays and not dictionaries. So thats why I put the dictionary in an array. Is that not accurate?

Comment: @user12669401 IDK who told you that, but you should clarify with them 1) Is this exactly what they meant? I suspect not 2) What are they hoping to achieve with dictionaries? In your case, I don't see why you wouldn't just use a struct, or maybe even a tuple

Comment: @user12669401 The fact that you are using “I am *told* that collection views work best with arrays” as a reason for using arrays suggests to me that you don’t really know how to use collection views... anyway, using an array here is appropriate, but you’ve got the wrong kind of array. As Alexander said, you shouldn’t use an array of dictionaries, as you’d end up storing one KVP in each dictionary. For a better choice, see the latter half of the answer.

Comment: Thanks you both for the recos. I will change them as you suggested.